# android: Linear Layout?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I created Linear Layout with some views.

In bottom:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button01"
    android:text="button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:background="@color/colorButton"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

I want to place that button in layout bottom. But there is bottom space. I don't know how to remove that space. Following is my code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
        app:titleTextColor="@android:color/white"
        app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp">
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="12">

    <TextView
        android:text="Price:"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center|bottom"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:paddingLeft="2dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"/>

    <org.florescu.android.rangeseekbar.RangeSeekBar
        android:id="@+id/range_seekbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        app:showLabels="false"
        app:textAboveThumbsColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:barHeight="5dp"
        app:defaultColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:activeColor="@color/colorButton"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:text="block"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center|bottom"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:paddingLeft="2dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:text="floor"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center|bottom"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:paddingLeft="2dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="5">

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button01"
        android:text="button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:background="@color/colorButton"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

range seeker gradle is
**compile 'org.florescu.android.rangeseekbar:rangeseekbar-library:0.3.0'**

**Edited: It's from "range seeker bar." But still don't know how to remove** space.

Comment: remove  android:layout_margin="5dp" from the Button

Comment: nothing changed

Comment: it is very strange. I have been tested this and it is works for me. There is a screenshot https://ibb.co/iyxQ55

Comment: Mine is like this : https://ibb.co/daHmCk

Answer (score 0):

Use the gravity property that android offers to the Button. If you want it to place to the bottom, set the gravity property to bottom like this.

```
android:gravity="bottom"
```

If you want to place it bottom at the center use android:gravity="bottom| center" and if you want it to be at bottom right use android:gravity="bottom|rigtht"

**Final code for the button:**

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button01"
    android:text="button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    **android:gravity="bottom"**
    android:background="@color/colorButton"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"/>
```

Comment: gravity can affect  button lining. Not outside

Comment: @GreedRuler - 2 problems:

1) Linear layout above the button is actually useless. You don't need that at all.
2) And also I think you have overallocated you weightsum. It should be 6 I believe.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the following line `android:layout_margin="5dp"/>`

Use the following and you will achieve what you want to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
    app:titleTextColor="@android:color/white"
    app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp">
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="12">

    <TextView
        android:text="Price:"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        **android:layout_weight="1"**
        android:gravity="center|bottom"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:paddingLeft="2dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"/>

    <org.florescu.android.rangeseekbar.RangeSeekBar
        android:id="@+id/range_seekbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        **android:layout_weight="3"**
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        app:showLabels="false"
        app:textAboveThumbsColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:barHeight="5dp"
        app:defaultColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:activeColor="@color/colorButton"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:text="block"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        **android:layout_weight="1"**
        android:gravity="center|bottom"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:paddingLeft="2dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:text="floor"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        **android:layout_weight="1"**
        android:gravity="center|bottom"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:paddingLeft="2dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        **android:layout_weight="5"**>

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button01"
        android:text="button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        **android:layout_weight="1"**
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        />

  </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in Your Weight allocation do it properly()

```
android:weightSum="12"
```

but the Total Weight in Your Layout is only 4(Sum of all layout weights). Do it in Proper Way  (or) simply Remove all weights

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
        app:titleTextColor="@android:color/white"
        app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp">
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

        <TextView
            android:text="Price:"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:gravity="center|bottom"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:paddingLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"/>


        <TextView
            android:text="block"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"

            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center|bottom"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:paddingLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:text="floor"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"

            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center|bottom"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:paddingLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="5">


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button01"
            android:text="button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It's from "range seeker bar." But still don't know how to remove space.

Comment: Nope try to remove all weights and give it as wrap content set layout gravity for button as  bottom

Comment: Try the Updated Code @GreedRuler

Comment: if i remove weight how much it can be responsive (display size)?

Answer (score 0):

you need to give weight sum 1 and than divided as per your need
Instead of using this
 `android:weightSum="12"` to this

```
android:weightSum="1".
```